# Can I hide quests I don't want to do?

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

I don't really care about the Springfield Heights quests. They're annoying and take a lot of time and resources. Is there a way for me to remove them from my quest log so I can basically ignore them forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any way of hiding quests in Tapped Out. So the quests will remain until you finally decide to do them.